# how to get X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test from Pycaret?

Tags: pycaret

can we get the X_train, y_train,X_test,y_test from a tuned model in `pycaret`?
I want the splits so that I can plot a few graphs which are not supported by `plot_model` in pycaret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_config(variable: str)` function.

Example:

```
get_config('X_test')
```

Please, check out documentation here: https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classification.html